# eslint/standard gives paring error

Tags: eslint, standardjs

I'm using standardJS (eslint). For this line I do get a `parsing error: Unexpected token = (null)`, which I do not understand:

```
static displayName = `WithData(${getComponentDisplayName(ComposedComponent)})`
```

Do I have to add any configuration? I am just using this in my package.json:

```
"standard": {
  "env": [
    "mocha"
  ],
  "global": [
    "React"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does helper funciton WithData start with a capital letter?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but I almost never see `\`` instead of a `'`

Comment: Is this line within a `class`? It's probably expecting `displayName` [to be a method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) as class-level fields aren't yet part of the language. They're currently a "Stage 3" [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#active-proposals).

Comment: @DavidLee [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Learned something new today, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've added the `"parser": "babel-eslint"` option for standardJS.